# Recommended rotor disc combination for Ranger truck. Normal usage

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

Any recommendations for brake rotor and brake pad combination for good stopping power. My rotors warped after 185,000 miles. I am easy on my brakes; first set of pads lasted 150,000 miles. This is for a 2001 Ranger 2 wd; I do my own maintenance. I do not mind spending extra for quality.
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping questions are off-topic on this SE.